# Difference in instantiating a variable using parenthesis and not

Tags: c#, instance

Difference in instantiating a variable using parentencis and not

with parentheses

```
var myCity = new CityDto()
{
   Id = 1,
   Name = "NY"
};
```

Without parentheses

```
var myCity = new CityDto
{
   Id = 1,
   Name = "NY"
};
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no difference.  When calling the default constructor, but using the object initializer syntax, the `()` can be removed.

If you were to remove the object initializer, the `()` are required.